# Multiple threads on I/O completion ports

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, io-completion-ports

I'm working on a C++ socket server using I/O completion ports. I create one I/O port and two worker threads per processor as some articles recommend in order to handle the overlapped I/O activity

From what I've read only one of these worker threads should be waking up and handling an I/O request at any time. So what I would expect when one client connects (only) and sends something is only one thread to wake up and handle that receive, but when I try to debug it I can see that multiple threads wake up and try to handle the same operation.

Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: How do you determine that multiple threads are handling the *same* operation?

Comment: What have you done to make to stop both threads reading from the same socket?

Comment: You specify the maximum number of concurrent threads when you create the IOCP. If you're getting multiple threads processing the same item then something in your code is in error. This IOCP overview might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I place a breakpoint within my "messageReceived" function that I would expect to be called once since the message I receive is small enough to fit within my buffer. At the moment I have a critical section to protect the access to the receive buffer of my client and I have separate receive and send buffers in each client. When I create the IOCP I pass 0 as the number of threads thus letting the OS decide what to do.

Comment: IIRC, this is possible if there are multiple WSARecv I/O requests queued up from multiple threads.  IOCP can signal completion of I/O to multiple worker threads for one client socket - the kernel IOCP threadPool fills up the buffers passed in the IO requests as fast as it can and submits them to the completion queue & so multiple buffers containing data from a single client can end up being handled by different work threads.  A 'message' small enough to fit in one I/O buffer does not guarantee that the data will all get loaded onto one buffer - it may still get split over two or more.